# Create view in a different database with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

As part of a larger project I'm trying to create a new view on each database in a SQL Server instance.

I've created a stored procedure that among other things is looping through the databases in the instance via a cursor then trying to create the view using `sp_executesql`.  Unfortunately the stored procedure does not exist in the databases that I am trying to create the views on.  So I'm trying to get sql server to use that database and then run the create view script.  When I run this I receive the error

> 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statment in a query batch.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?
Here is the `sp_executesql` portion of the procedure.

```
declare @DB VARCHAR(50)
declare @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
set @DB = '[dbname]'

SET @SQL =  N'USE ' + @DB + N' CREATE VIEW vNonhiddenCategories 
AS
SELECT categories.categoryid
FROM categories
--WHERE ... irrelevant remainder of view code ...
'
execute sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will require really having fun with escaping and re-escaping single quotes, but I think the technique you're after is:

```
DECLARE 
  @DB  NVARCHAR(255) = QUOTENAME(N'dbname'),
  @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL =  N'EXEC ' + @DB + '.sys.sp_executesql '
+ 'N''CREATE VIEW dbo.vWhatever
AS
  SELECT x = 1, y = ''''x'''', z = GETDATE();''';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

So you're kind of nesting the dynamic SQL; the inner one ensures that the SQL is executed at the target database, not locally.

Another way that I've picked up since this original question appeared:

```
DECLARE 
  @DB  NVARCHAR(255) = QUOTENAME('dbname'),
  @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @DBExec NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DBExec = @DB + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

SET @SQL = N'CREATE VIEW dbo.whatever
  AS
    SELECT x = 1, y = ''x'', z = GETDATE();';

EXEC @DBExec @SQL;
```

This is slightly tidier because you don't have to double-nest single quotes.

And here is a slightly tidier way to do it without cursors (well, without all the scaffolding of setting up a cursor). Note that the inner dynamic SQL will only be executed in databases where (a) a categories table exists (b) this view does not already exist and (c) it is not a system database (well, not one of the primary system databases, anyway).

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @SQL += NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)    
  + N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + '.sys.views WHERE name = ''vNonhiddenCategories'')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name)
  + '.sys.tables WHERE name = ''categories'')
  BEGIN
    EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.sp_executesql N''
    CREATE VIEW dbo.vNonhiddenCategories3
    AS
      SELECT x = 1, y = ''''x'''';''
  END'
  FROM sys.databases 
  WHERE database_id BETWEEN 5 AND 32766;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Of course "tidier" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: That's awesome.  Don't know why it didnt occur to me to nest it like that but well done sir.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use for each database :

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?] 

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) 

SET @SQL =''CREATE VIEW AS ...
BEGIN
EXEC  [?].sys.sp_executesql @SQL 
END'
```

Comment: This undocumented stored proc is *not* reliable. [sp_ineachdb](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql) is a much better alternative.